# Confusion about rank and shape in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am confused about rank and shape concept of TensorFlow. I have read the details from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/resources/dims_types.html) and did run some code to clear my concept about them. But I am still confused and need help to understand.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 12])
print(x.get_shape()) # ==> (2, 12)
print(x[0, :].get_shape())  # ==> (12,)
print(x[1, :].get_shape())  # ==> (12,)
print(x[2, :].get_shape())  # ==> (12,)
print(x[120, :].get_shape())  # ==> (12,)
```

I thought `x` is like a 2d matrix where `2` is `number of rows` and `12` is `number of columns`. Then why I am getting shape for `x[120, :]` as `(12, )`? How even `x[120, :]` is possible with the given shape?

Besides, since I thought x is a 2D tensor, its rank is also 2 because dimension and rank is the same thing for tensors (according to my understanding). But when I run:

```
print(x[0].get_shape())
```

I am getting this error:

```
Shape (2, 12) must have rank 1
```

It means my understanding is wrong about rank and dimension. What I am missing about rank and dimensions? Is rank and dimension two different things? How the rank of `tensor x` in the above example is 1? How can I set the rank of a tensor? Can anyone explain in details with some comprehensive examples?

Comment: `x[0]` should work with the latest version of tensorflow, try to update tensorflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/resources/dims_types.html) you provide very clear.

---

The rank of a tensor is the **number of dimensions** it has

- a matrix has 2 dimensions, so its rank is 2
- a colored image has 3 dimensions `[height, width, 3]` so its rank is 3

The shape of a tensor is the detailed number of components in each dimension

- a matrix has 2 dimensions, rank 2 and can have a shape like `[6, 10]`, where `6` is the number of rows and `10` the number of columns
- a 200x200 colored image (of rank 3) will have a shape `[200, 200, 3]`

---

For your examples, `x[120, :]` is possible to write because TensorFlow is not checking yet if `120` is a valid index. When you create your session and run the code, you will find an error:

```
res = x[120, :]

with tf.Session():
    sess.run(res, feed_dict={x: np.zeros((2, 12))})
```

> InvalidArgumentError: slice index 120 of dimension 0 out of bounds.

---

As said in my comment, `x[0]` should work with the latest version of TensorFlow and it should give a tensor of shape `(12,)`, and rank 1.

Comment: i am using tensorflow 0.10. can you tell me, what is the meaning of this statement - Shape (2, 12) must have rank 1? shape(2, 12) means a matrix, then how a matrix's rank can be 1? what you said is clear to me but is it possible a matrix's rank be 1?

Comment: In version 0.10, I think you could only write `x[0]` for tensors of rank 1. If you wanted to get the first row of a matrix, you had to specify `x[0, :]`, so that's why you got the error. This is fixed in v0.11

Comment: My question was - how Shape (2, 12) represents rank 1? It should be rank 2 because we have defined two dimensions in Shape. Forget about tensorflow version, i understood the version issue.

Comment: So when you do `x[0]`, TensorFlow expects `x` to be of rank 1. In your case, `x` is a matrix of shape `(2, 12)` and rank `2`, so TensorFlow is throwing an error `Shape (2, 12) must have rank 1`. Obviously the shape `(2, 12)` will never have rank 1, so what the message means is "Your tensor has shape `(2, 12)`, but we want rank 1 here"

Comment: I got it now. thanks a lot. just one last question for clarification: is rank and dimension same always? If not, can you give an example in your post. one more thing for clarification, shape contains #values equal to dimension, is that correct?

Comment: The rank is the same as the dimension yes (in practice, a matrix of rank 2 will be said to be 2-dimensional). The shape will have a value for each dimension, so the length of the shape is the rank.

Comment: Why is the shape of `x[0]`, which has rank 1, rendered as `(12,)`. Wouldn't `(12)` convey the same information?

Comment: In python, `(12)` is the same as `12`. The shape is always a tuple so if it has one element you need to write `(12,)`.

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis, I found that while declaring tensor the number of square braces used gives the rank of a tensor. And the number of values in a shape is equal to the rank. For example:

```
a1=tf.constant(
[   
    [
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        [1,2,3,4,5]
    ]
]
)
```

Here, I used 3 square braces. So the rank is 3. Also the shape would be in the format (x,y,z) since the rank is 3.

Now the values of x,y and z:

x= Number of  commas in the first brace plus 1
so x=0+1=1

similarly
y=3+1=4

z=4+1=5

Finally the rank is 3 and shape is (1,4,5)